# How to center a qcircuit

Tags: qcircuit

I want to centre my circuit under figure command but I got it in the left, my code is:

```
\begin{figure}
     \centering 
\Qcircuit @C=2em @R=1.5em {
\lstick{\ket{\psi}} & \qw & \qw & \ctrl{1} &\gate{H} & \meter & \control \cw \cwx[2]\\
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{H} & \ctrl{1} & \targ & \qw &\meter & \cwx[1]\\ \lstick{\ket{0}} & \qw & \targ & \qw &\qw & \gate{X} \cwx & \gate{Z} \cwx &\rstick{\ket{\psi}} \qw}    
 \caption{Quantum teleportation}
     \label{fig:my_label}
 \end{figure}
```

Comment: did the answer suit your requirement

Comment: @jsbibra It does, thank you

Comment: waiting for your upvote and acceptance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation qcircuit should be centered in an array environment -- additionally for the caption the table environment is also added

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage[braket]{qcircuit}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]


\[
\begin{array}{c}

\Qcircuit @C=2em @R=1.5em {
     \lstick{\ket{\psi}} & 
        \qw & 
            \qw & 
                \ctrl{1} &
                    \gate{H} & 
                        \meter & 
                            \control \cw \cwx[2]\\
    \lstick{\ket{0}} & 
        \gate{H} & 
            \ctrl{1} & 
                \targ & 
                    \qw &
                        \meter & 
                            \cwx1\\
    \lstick{\ket{0}} & 
        \qw & 
            \targ & 
                \qw &
                    \qw & 
                        \gate{X} \cwx & 
                            \gate{Z} \cwx &
                                \rstick{\ket{\psi}} \qw
        }

\end{array}
\]
\caption{Quantum teleportation} \label{fig:my_label} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```